# Why are translations getting updated when there are no modifications to them?

Tags: launchpad, translation

I have a branch in Launchpad that's set to automatically import translations to the branch. However, I noticed that there have been a lot of 'useless commits' lately where the translation files would be updated even though there were no changes to them.

For example, [this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stackapplet/trunk/revision/84) revision:

```
fr.po:17
- "X-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2011-05-01 05:32+0000\n"
+ "X-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2011-05-02 05:32+0000\n"
```

Why are the translations getting updated when there are no *actual* changes?

Notice on [this](https://translations.launchpad.net/stackapplet/trunk/+translations) page that the modification times are for last year:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the ['"Bouncing" between branch imports and branch exports.' bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/490668), to which I'd suggest you to add a comment to bring it to the attention of developers.

On the other hand, I've had a look at the [translations settings for your project](https://translations.launchpad.net/stackapplet/trunk/+translations-settings) and I see that you are using automatic exports but not automatic imports. Is there any reason for that?

Cheers,
David.

Comment: There's no reason... I guess I just don't quite understand how translation importing / exporting works.